# Unit testing vs Integration testing of an Express.js app

Tags: node.js, express, mocha.js, sinon, supertest

I'm writing tests for an Express.js app and I don't know how to choose between unit tests and integration tests.

currently I experimented with:

unit tests - using Sinon for stubs/mocks/spies and Injects for dependency injection to modules. with this approach I have to stub MongoDB and other external methods.

I thought about unit testing the individual routes and then using an integration test to verify that the correct routes are actually invoked.

integration tests - using Supertest and Superagent, much less code to write (no need to mock/stub anything) but  a test environment should exist (databases, etc..)

I'm using Mocha to run both styles of tests.

how should I choose between those two different approaches ?

Answer (score 1):

You should probably do both. Unit test each non-helper method that does non-trivial work. Run the whole thing through a few integration tests. If you find yourself having to do tons and tons and tons of mocks and stubs, it's probably a sign to refactor.

Comment: what is your suggestion for routes that do standard database CRUD ?

Comment: Factor the CRUD into some object/class/function, and unit test that. Then integrate test your routes.